# asus zephyrus gu502gv what does work with ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, asus

I'm thinking about buying ASUS Zephyrus GU502GV, and I want to use Ubuntu as my primary OS.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with the install and the drivers for this laptop?

What does and doesn't work on Ubuntu with this laptop?

Are there any drivers for Ubuntu ?

The specs:
[https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-ROG-GU502GV-i7-9750H-2060-16GB/dp/B07RDJ8PC5?ref_=d6k_applink_bb_marketplace](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RDJ8PC5)